# the fishing rod bowing like a question mark (baʊiŋ vs. bouiŋ)

Tags: word-usage, pronunciation

> the fishing rod bowing like a question mark

What's the pronunciation: baʊiŋ vs. bouiŋ?

Comment: IMO a bow (/bəʊ/) as used by an archer, not a bow (/baʊ/) as given to a Queen. The first is under stress, the second is for respect.

Comment: What's the pronunciation for the OP's example?

Comment: As shown in the comment and audible examples for each meaning are in [Lexico](https://www.lexico.com/definition/bow).

Comment: OP's question is not in the audible exampels for each meaning. It seems that the OP already knows the meanings but he wants to be sure of pronunciation in terms of the example sentence.

Comment: Please listen to the pronuniation of **bow¹**, a weapon for shooting arrows, or a curved rod used for playing the violin (/bəʊ/).

Comment: They don't give the pronuniation of the participle 'bowing' but it is predictably like adding '-ing' to the noun's pronunciation given.

Comment: Yes,  OP=Brandon.  It is unusual for the OP to refer to "The OP" and "he".  In English, the first person is used when speaking about yourself.  So your comment should have been "What is the pronunciation in *my* example". And "My question is not in audible examples.... I already know the meaning, but I want to be sure of the pronunciation..."

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Probably  /bəʊiŋ/ (like bow and arrow, bending under stress), though it could be a metaphorical use as /baʊiŋ/  because it appears to be humble.  Both readings are possible, although the first is much more likely.

Comment: The first is _very much_ more likely. Did I ever mention that for approx 5 decades I said David Jones' stage name ('Bowie') surname as if 'Bow- ' was the gesture of respect? I heard BBC people say it too. I see that Zowie now calls himself Duncan Jones. Sensible fellow.